# How to increase the width/size of markers line in watershed?

Tags: python

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage
from skimage import measure, color, io
from skimage.restoration import denoise_nl_means, estimate_sigma
from skimage.filters import roberts, sobel, scharr, prewitt
from tqdm import tqdm
import os
import glob
from skimage.io import imread, imshow
from skimage import exposure 

sure_bg = cv2.dilate(invert,kernel,iterations=2)

#plt.imshow(sure_bg)
dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(invert,cv2.DIST_L2,3)

ret2, sure_fg = cv2.threshold(dist_transform,0.2*dist_transform.max(),255,0)

sure_fg = np.uint8(sure_fg)

#plt.imshow(sure_fg)    
unknown = cv2.subtract(sure_bg,sure_fg)

#plt.imshow(unknown)
ret3, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(sure_fg)

markers = markers+10
markers[unknown==255] = 0
markers = cv2.watershed(img1,markers)

org_img[markers == -1] = [255,69,0]  
img2 = color.label2rgb(markers, bg_label=0)
```

Comment: you should describe problem in question's body, not in title. And you could add more details what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use the function [watershed](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.watershed) from the module sci-kit image, because it has the parameter `watershed_line`. You can dilate the watershed lines after you detect the lines.

```
from skimage.segmentation import watershed
from skimage.morphology import dilation
from skimage.morphology import square
import numpy as np 

markers = watershed(-dist_transform, markers, mask=sure_fg , watershed_line=True)
watershed_lines = np.zeros(shape=np.shape(markers))
watershed_lines(markers==0)=1 # ws lines are labeled as 0 in markers
watershed_lines_thick = dilation(bright_pixel, square(3))
```

There might be some typos since I did not check any results. But hope you get the idea. Let me know if it helps!